# How does Vector256.Shuffle work in .Net 7+?

Tags: c#, simd, intrinsics

Avx2.Shuffle uses _mm256_shuffle_epi8 to shuffle bytes within 128-bit lanes depending on a mask, zeroing values if the final bit is set.

How does `Vector256.Shuffle` work? Unlike `Avx2.Shuffle` it will zero if the shuffle control mask value exceeds the number of elements. In addition it supports cross lane shuffling.

I'm guessing it uses a combination of checking for a constant shuffle mask, using _mm256_cmpgt_epi8 with masking to zero elements and _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 when cross lane shuffling is required.

How would I see what IL code is emitted at runtime? I don't think SharpLab does - [my example](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

edit I've never looked at the jit source code before but [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8d9114b7e4a7937002fb7013f26cdd3e5c9d1446/src/coreclr/jit/hwintrinsicxarch.cpp#L2108) appears to show that the jit will check if any shuffle indices exceed its lane, falling back to the manual version if indices do fall out of bounds, otherwise it will use the relevant Avx instruction. This is my best guess, I haven't the faintest idea how the jit works.

Comment: A more relevant part of the code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/23283ffabac13d979d0e1b2e71c51c467544dd21/src/coreclr/jit/gentree.cpp#L21338)

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I struggled to find `gtNewSimdShuffleNode`.

Comment: For whatever reason that I don't understand yet, github just refused to find it. But it found the commit that introduced the function and I found it that way.

Comment: Why not put some code inside a function on SharpLab and look at the JIT asm?  Write a function that takes an arg (or loads from memory and stores a result).  Your SharpLab link doesn't do anything with the results so they can get optimized away, and/or they're compile-time constants.  And they're not in a function at all, which seems weird to me, but I don't know C#.

Comment: Holy crap, your updated SharpLab link that uses the intrinsic in a separate function shows it using a scalar loop; note the `jl short L0020`.  (After it copies the stack arg to elsewhere in the stack frame.  After the loop it reloads into a vector, creating a store-forwarding stall.)  Same scalar loop that was part of the unnamed global-scope code, which I'd assumed must be something else!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Shuffle method in .Net7, always uses scalar fallback code. I've tested it on both X86 and Arm platforms and found that it is not hardware accelerated.

To solve the problem of the Shuffle method not being hardware accelerated, I developed the VectorTraits library. It supports both X86 and Arm platforms.

- X86 platform: Use _mm256_shuffle_epi8 and other instructions.
- Arm platforms: Use vqvtbl1q_u8 and other instructions.

The methods is as follows.

- [Vector256s.Shuffle](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.Shuffle.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_Shuffle_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Shuffle and clear. If the indices value is out of range, the element will be cleared.
- [Vector256s.YShuffleInsert](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.YShuffleInsert.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_YShuffleInsert_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Shuffle and insert. If the index value is out of range, the elements of the background vector will be inserted.
- [Vector256s.YShuffleKernel](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.YShuffleKernel.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_YShuffleKernel_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Only shuffle. If the index value is out of range, the result is undefined.

Not only for Vector256, but also for Vector128 and [Vector](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vectors.Shuffle.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vectors_Shuffle_System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__), this library provides a Shuffle method.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/VectorTraits

Comment: Note that AVX-512VBMI `vpermb` can do lane-crossing 8-bit shuffles.  (Available on Ice Lake and later.)  The zeroing for out-of-bounds could be accomplished with a compare to set up for a zero-masking `vpermb ymm{k1}{z}, ymm2, ymm3`.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermb)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly which .NET version the following link has, but it should be some recent version: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/Intrinsics/Vector256.cs,2366

Comment: This is the scalar fallack code, I want to see what is emited at runtime. For instance the source code for Avx doesn't appear to do anything but uses `_mm256_shuffle_epi8`